# How to implement monotonicity constraints using Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, constraints

I have two vectors: a features vector X and an importance vector W - it represents weight of every X element. Weights they are calculated analytically from X( in a very complex way using domain knowledge and are in some complex way correlated with X).

If Wi > Wn than Yi > Yn. So Y is monotonic with respect to the W. And I want to use this constrain.

X, W and Y are big (2500). I am using Multi layer fully connected network for predictions Y from X.

How can I implement this constrain using Tensorflow /Keras? I think about some custom loss using this contain but can't implement it effectively. Any idea?

Comment: Even if you express the constraint in a loss function, the loss will likely never be exactly 0 and the model can still produce non-monotonic results. You could then just enforce the monotonicity on Y as a post-processing step after inference.

Comment: I believe with good loss model can learn some interpolation Y with respect to W and produce better results. I think if the model will be able to learn this  instead of  sorting Y by W approach (that has problems with differentiation), that can have good results.